# How should I shape my Schema Design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, database-schema

I want to create a client billing app. I need to keep price specific to each client. So I need a Price table for every client. If someone can help with how to shape the schema.
Thanks Ryuu
[image: Here is My Schema Still Under Work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are selling specific products, and each product has, or potentially has, a different price for each client, then you would create a pricing table with foreign keys of client id and product id. That is, for each client, for each product, there is a price record. You then have a many-to-one relationship of price to client and a many-to-one relationship of price to product.

If you have many products, I'd guess you don't price every product separately for every client. Like if you have 200 products and you acquire a new client, you probably don't make up a price for every one of those 200 products just for that client. In that case you're more likely to have price lists. Some clients get the "A" list, some get the "B" list, etc. Then you'd create a price_list table and relate prices to the price_list, and then relate price_list to client. This is how my company does its pricing: we have one set of prices for standard commercial customers, another for our biggest customers, and a third for non-profits. Then each customer just has to be related to the appropriate list, not to all the individual products.

Alternatively, you might have "base" prices for each product and some clients get a discount. Then you'd just need a price for each product, and a percentage discount for each client.

There could be other ways to do it depending on how you do your pricing.